# programmatically print out cell and comments contents from spreadsheet

Tags: excel, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, libreoffice

I have a spreadsheet with worksheets (originally in Google Sheets, but I can export to .xlsx or .ods) and I would like to programmatically print out the cell values of the first line along with the comments in each cell. E.g. see screenshot below of worksheet (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DGsrEKrxfQm8sRzfLyqu4z6Hx8eDdkVDiYlN3Rwve6A/edit?usp=sharing):

[image]

There are 3 cells in row1 each with a comment in them.

I would like to programmatically print out the contents of this worksheet so that they look something like:

```
Cell:"field1",Comment:"key=foobar"
Cell:"field2",Comment:"key=bar"
Cell:"field3",Comment:"key=foobar"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Downvoting because the question does not show authors effort or research made.

Answer (score 1):

[google-spreadsheets](/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheets)

```
function getNotes_(fileId, sheetName, rangeA1)
{
  var data = [];
  var file = SpreadsheetApp.openById(fileId);
  var sheet = file.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var range = sheet.getRange(rangeA1);  
  var values = range.getValues();
  var notes = range.getNotes();  
  var getResult_ = function(value, i) { data.push( 'Cell:"' + value + '",Comment:"' + rowNotes[i] +'"') }; 
  var rowNotes = [];
  for (var i = 0, l = values.length; i < l; i++)
  {
    rowNotes = notes[i];
    values[i].forEach(getResult_);    
  }  
  return data;    
}
```

Comment: That tag is deleted. We now only have [tag:google-sheets].